# Not receiving any audio from anonymously joined user

Tags: android, skypedeveloper

I'm currently developing an app which uses the Skype for Business API for Android. When an anonymous user joins a meeting he can hear other people in the meeting, but not the other around. Video works perfectly both ways. I tried adjusting the conversation via

```
this.configurationManager.setRequireWiFiForAudio(false);
```

and the AudioService class.

I then tried the demo app at https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/GuestMeetingJoin
There was also no audio coming from the anonymous user using the app.

And yes, I am aware that anonymous users joining a meeting must be first unmuted to speak.

What is the problem, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
You have to unmute yourself in the participantsList.

```
if (this.audioService.canToggleMute()) {
    try {
        this.audioService.toggleMute();
    } catch (SFBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unmuting an anonymous participant as the meeting leader appears to do nothing, so make sure you unmute everybody programatically.